# Can I reference local files in a webview when I use navigatetostring?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm using a webview to display certain data in my windows 8 app.  I would like to user an include to a local js file as well as use locally stored images.

Is this possible?

I haven't had any luck by putting the local path where the files are located.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `WebView` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) you can only reference other files using the `ms-appx-web` protocol, i.e. to load the files stored in `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation`, meaning that they need to be distributed as content along with your application. The control doesn't support `ms-appdata` protocol for security reasons, i.e. you can't open files stored `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RemoteFolder` or `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TempFolder` where you'd need to put them if you were generating or downloading them at runtime.

In JavaScript apps `WebView` is a bit more [flexible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx): it does support `ms-appdata` protocol as well, but only for media files such as images. It cannot open any potentially executable code, such as script or CSS.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for the help. I apologize for not finding it in the documentation myself.

Comment: Is this still true nowadays? I thought I had read that ms-appdata URLs are supported now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open some local .html file or atc. you should download it in **`InstalledLocation`** folder. If you haven't option to create a new file you can just use `file.CopyAsync(htmlFolder, fname + ".html");`
 For example I create some .html file:

```
StorageFolder htmlFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFolderAsync(@"HtmlFiles", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
IStorageFile file = await htmlFolder .CreateFileAsync(fname + ".html", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

and than I can easily open this .html file with or without `FileOpenPicker`:

```
var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".html");
var file = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
   string myPath = file.Path.Substring(file.Path.IndexOf("HtmlFiles"));
   myWebview.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///" + myPath));
}
```

And don't forget - just only from **`InstalledLocation`** you can open it with `ms-appx-web:///`

Answer (score 0):

If the WebView is IE10 based, FIleReader may be what you are looking for. Here is a snippet of code that I use on an image ipload page to show images in a page when they are selected via a File Open dialog:

```
$('input:file').each(function(index, evt){
    if(index===0)
    {
        var files = evt.files;
        for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            if(files[i].name===filename)
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload=(function(theFile){
                    return function(e){
                        var line= uploader.fineUploader('getItemByFileId',id);
                        if(line!=undefined)
                            $(line).append('<img class="fileimage" id="fileImage-' + id + '" src="'+e.target.result+'" />');
                    };
                })(files[i]);
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this points you in the right direction!